# controllerclassnamehandlermapping request url

Tags: spring-mvc

I knew that ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping mapped by ControllerclassName.

MyController is like below.

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping
    public String onlyUrl(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "test get or post");
        return "showMessage";
    }
}
```

and below is my config

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping">
```

when I request http://localhost:9090/testapp/test it works well.

but when I request http://localhost:9090/testapp/hello  it still works.

Is it right?

Comment: You have not mapped to specific urls. For default handler it mapps the onlyUrl() function. Try specifying the urls in the @RequestMapping annotation.

Comment: Thanks Jango. But by default, first method(onlyUrl) will be mapped to /test. Aren't you?

Comment: See only url will be mapped to default handler "/". So what ever the url which is valid will redirect to "onlyUrl" function. I think even http://localhost:9090/testapp/ should give you same result. This can only be restricted by explicitly giving request mapping